# git force push after rebase still shows "This branch is out-of-date with the base branch" on Github

Tags: git, github, rebase

I am working on a feature branch but before pushing to github for a PR, I wanted to rebase my branch onto the *latest* `main` for which I ran the following commands:

```
git checkout main
git pull origin main // get the latest version
git checkout feature_branch
git rebase main 
git push -f origin feature_branch
```

Even though the push was successful, and `git log` shows my local branch's history contains the latest commits from `main` however my PR on Github says **This branch is out-of-date with the base branch**.

I have previously used merge commit via `git pull origin main` in a local branch and it has always worked but apparently that's not a recommended approach.

How come the remote `main` branch isn't in-sync with the local despite local containing the latest commits from `main`?

**Edit:**

one thing I did notice getting upon running `git rebase main` was:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
```

It didn't seem like an error and running `git log` confirmed that the rebase seemed successful.

Comment: It's definitely not a problem with the way you did the flow... it looks _ok_ **if** the upstream of your feature branch is `main`.... but I wonder if you can find out what the upstream branch _github_ thinks it is for the feature branch. My hunch is that it will be something other than `main`.

Comment: `git remote show origin`  lists my feature branch under `Local refs configured for 'git push'` and shows it's `(up to date)`

Comment: Maybe you just get unlikely and `main` actually got updated again since your `pull` command? If that's not it, you should be able to see the commits GH thinks `main` and `feature_branch` are on. Does `feature_branch` tip commit match the commit ID that you just pushed? If no, is it possible you just need to refresh the PR? If still no, is it the same repo you pushed to?

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't run `git pull` for this problem (I mentioned previously I have used it when I didn't use `rebase`). I confirmed the latest commit ID on `feature_branch`'s on GH matches with what I have locally (via `git log`).

Comment: It was kind of a dumb of me to not figure out I guess but it was tricky since I assumed there would be no additional commits to `main` after I rebased hence the remote branch being out of date. Thanks @TTT

Comment: Note that *Git* does not have the concept of a "base branch"; that's a *GitHub* thing (as are pull requests themselves). Git does have the concept of an "upstream" for a branch, but it's not quite the same.

Comment: Try refreshing the PR page on GitHub. Also double check what the target and source branches are for the PR.

Comment: The output you note from `git rebase main` is typical. This is just the logging output of `git rebase` which indicates things are proceeding as they should.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that GIT will throw the "this branch is out-of-date with the base branch." error if the rebase went well. I would suggest rechecking the logs on your branch using git log --oneline.

Comment: something I should specifically look for in the output of `git log --oneline`?

Comment: Just ensure, that you have all the commits from the base branch followed by the commits from your feature branch.

Comment: Like I said, `git log` shows my local commits are on top of the latest commits from `main` which tells me `git rebase` was a success

Answer (score 0):

One way to check if `main` got updated on the remote is to just run `git fetch`, then check the state of `origin/main` :

```
git fetch
# view combined history of origin/main and your own branch :
git log --graph --oneline origin/main feature_branch
```